# Animated background not resize when the expanding the browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, resize, event-listener

I have an animated binary rain background for a website and it works fine except for when I expand the tab (resize the screen), however, the background does not adjust and the expanded area is left blank. I have included an event listener function which should resize the canvas to the size of the window but I'm not sure why it isn't working. Here's the JS code:

```
// Get a reference to the canvas element and its 2D rendering context
var canvas = document.getElementById("binary-rain-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Function to set the canvas size based on window dimensions
function setCanvasSize() {
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
}

// Initialize the canvas size
setCanvasSize();

// Define the characters to use for the rain and split them into an array
var binaryChars = "01";
binaryChars = binaryChars.split("");

// Set the font size for the raindrops
var fontSize = 20;

// Calculate the number of columns based on canvas width and font size
var numColumns = canvas.width / fontSize;

// Initialize an array to track the position of each raindrop
var dropPositions = [];

// Initialize the drop positions with an initial value of 1
for (var column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
dropPositions[column] = 1;
}

// Function to draw the binary rain animation
function drawBinaryRain() {
// Set the background color with some transparency
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Set the color of the raindrops
ctx.fillStyle = "#01DFEF";

// Set the font for the raindrops
ctx.font = fontSize + "px courier new";

// Loop through each column and update the raindrop positions
for (var i = 0; i < dropPositions.length; i++) {
    // Select a random binary character
    var binaryChar = binaryChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * binaryChars.length)];

    // Draw the binary character at the current position
    ctx.fillText(binaryChar, i * fontSize, dropPositions[i] * fontSize);

    // Check if the raindrop has reached the bottom and reset it randomly
    if (dropPositions[i] * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
        dropPositions[i] = 0;
    }

    // Increment the position for the next frame
    dropPositions[i]++;
}
}

// Call the drawBinaryRain function repeatedly to create the animation
setInterval(drawBinaryRain, 120);

// Event listener to adjust canvas size when the window is resized
window.addEventListener("resize", setCanvasSize);
```

Here's the corresponding html code if helpful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>About Page</title>
</head>
<style>
body{
    background: #1d1f20;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <canvas id = "binary-rain-canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="about.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you calculate `dropPositions` only once